# What happens when a bolt fails to ack a tuple that it consumed from a particular stream of a spout?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

Say I have a spout which emmits the messages in a topic in to two streams( stream1 & stream2) and two bolts consume the messages from these streams(bolt1 -> stream1 ,bolt2 -> stream2).Now if bolt 2 fails to ack the tuple will the message be replayed only to bolt 2?According to the new consumer API in storm (apache-storm-1.0.2) a retry mechanism is implemented in which if numFail> maxRetry then tuple is acked by storm.My doubt is what happens to the message after it is acked this way? will it be removed from the kafka queue itself? If so we'll loose some messages which have failed.Can someone please enlighten me on the lifecycle of a tuple and what happens to a message starting from kafka to storm , when it fails to be acked.

Answer (score 1):

If only one bolt acks the tuple but not the second one, the tuple will be replayed to both bolts.

Furthermore, if max retry is reached, Storm will not try to send this message again and drop. But it will not be removed the the original source (in your case it seems to be Kafka, for with deleting messages is not possible in the first place).

Comment: Does something like this happen -> if maxRetries are reached then the message is given to another consumer in the consumer group.To be clear, I'm trying to use the new consumer API provided in the newest version of storm (apache-storm-1.0.2).

Comment: No. The spout will just skip over this message and process the next one.

Comment: I'm deliberately setting collector.fail(tuple) in my bolt class.But  the messages are not replayed by spout.Can you please tell me what could the possible reason be. When I send a message to that bolt it's printed, as I have a print statement after which I do collector.fail(tuple) .I'm thus expecting the message to be replayed by the spout and so many times the same message has to be printed, which is not happening.I'm trying to use the new consumer API provided in the newest version of storm (apache-storm-1.0.2).

Comment: What Spout do you use? If it's a custom spout, you need to add the reply code by yourself. If a tuple fails `Spout#fail()` will be called, and you must reemit the tuple there.

Comment: I'm using KafkaSpout(KafkaSpoutConfig<K, V> kafkaSpoutConfig) provided by  org.apache.storm.kafka.spout. I can see fail and ack methods inside it.

Comment: Those should re-emit failed tuples. Can you double check, that those methods are called? Maybe you nee to increase log level.

Comment: Hey Matthias, as i'm calling explicity the collector.fail(tuple) in the bolt.I'm assuming the appropriate fail methods are called.I wouldn't be able to check explicity if the spouts fail method is called as The classes i'm using( KafkaSpout(KafkaSpoutConfig<K, V> kafkaSpoutConfig) ) are non editible as they are present inside the jars.What is increasing log level?

Comment: Hey, I've tried increasing the log level also after you've mentioned i.e., I've selected each of them and checked.only log.info and sysout are displayed.I Still don't get how this would help in understanding why the message is not being displayed multiple times when failed to be acked.

Comment: Running out of ideas... Sorry. SO is no debugging service.